# What is the purpose of the different types of Parse keys?

Tags: parse-platform

There are different keys for iOS(Client Key), Android(Client Key) and Windows Phone(.NET Key).

What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding (which isn't infallible), these keys are used so Parse can know what type of platform is connecting to which application.

Different platforms have different communication protocols, so Parse needs to know how to appropriately communicate with you.

Additionally, you don't want anyone to connect to you app. The id ensures that you're connecting to the right app. The key guarantees that it's you, and identifies your platform.

- **Application ID** : Used to uniquely identify your application
- **Client Key** : Used for Android and iOS connections
- **Javascript Key** : Used for JavaScript connection
- **.NET Key** : Used for Windows apps connections
- **Rest API Key** : Used for Rest API connections
- **Master Key** : Used for Rest API connections

*Note: The Master Key does not adhere to object-level permissions, while the other keys do.*

I found most of this from navigating to my App's settings page and clicking on keys.

Answer (score 1):

Application Id -This is the main identifier that uniquely specifies your application. This is paired with a key to provide your clients access to your application's data.

Client Key - This key should be used in consumer clients, like the iOS or Android SDK. It adheres to object level permissions.

JavaScript Key -This key should be used when making requests from JavaScript running on a user's machine. It adheres to object-level permissions.

.NET Key - This key should be used when making requests from a Windows application. It adheres to object-level permissions.

You can also check here.
Open your Parse account settings then open keys section and click question mark icon.